# Django Form and two forms with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have these models:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ID)

class CustomerAddresses(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    CustomerNoID = models.ForeignKey('Customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ID)
```

and my view:

```
def add_customer_view(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    last_customerno = Customers.objects.filter(UserID=user_id).order_by('CustomerNo').last()
    if not last_customerno:
        # return '0001'
        last_customerno = 1000
    if last_customerno == 1000:
        customerno_int = 1000
    else:
        customerno_int = last_customerno.CustomerNo + 1
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer_form = CustomerForm(request.user.id, request.POST)
        customer_address_form = CustomerAddressesForm(request.user.id, request.POST)
        if customer_form.is_valid():
            new_customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
            new_customer.save()
            if customer_address_form.is_valid():
                new_address = customer_address_form.save(commit=False)
                new_address.CustomerNoID = new_customer
                new_address.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/backend/kunder/')
    else:
        customer_form = CustomerForm(request.user.id, initial={'CustomerNo': customerno_int})
        customer_address_form = CustomerAddressesForm(request.user.id)
    return render(
        request,
        'backend/add_customer.html',
        {
            'title': 'WestcoastShop - Backend',
            'customer_form': customer_form,
            'customer_address_form': customer_address_form
        }
    )
```

But just the Customer is creating not the address I think the form is missing the CustomerNoID and I think I got the right way but after 6 hrs I give up maybe here is a smart guy how finds the error.

regards.

Comment: `customer_address_form` might not be valid. Also for some reason you pass `request.user.id` to your forms? Please show your forms and your template `add_customer.html`. Also what does `print(customer_address_form.errors)` give?

Comment: why you created another Model for the customer address ?

Comment: Because a Customer can have an shipping and an invoice address but it can be also just one ... I pass request.user.id because I filter a drop down list, and it works, and yes the address form is not valid because the ID of Customer will not be filled

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>CustomerNoID<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is needed.</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

I changed the form and added the second one in a modal so I can save the two models nondependent.